# Options for leveraging non-lethal damage

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, damage

What **options** exist for creating a **character focused on doing solely non-lethal damage**?  Are there ways to have increased damage output compared to a lethal-damage-dealing characters by accepting the restriction of being only able to do non-lethal damage as a trade-off?  Can a character that only deals non-lethal damage be built as a "high damage" character, relatively speaking?

Comment: In your second sentence, are you wondering whether it's possible to have a non-lethal damage dealer who deals _more damage than_ a comparable lethal damage dealer? (I think that's what you might mean, but the phrasing's odd to me)

Comment: @JonathanHobbs That is correct

Comment: It may be worth noting that in the real world it can be much harder to apply non-lethal force than (potentially) lethal force.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Nonlethal Damage

### Core

It's actually quite simple to do this.  In the SRD, you'll see a rule that allows you to [deal nonlethal damage with *any* weapon that normally deals lethal damage](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Nonlethal_Damage#Nonlethal_Damage_with_a_Weapon_that_Deals_Lethal_Damage):

> Nonlethal Damage with a Weapon that Deals Lethal Damage
>
> You can use a melee weapon that deals lethal damage to deal nonlethal damage instead, but you take a –4 penalty on your attack

... which makes sense.  You have to take much more care not to kill someone with a sword and just knock them out.  But the option is there for you!  And it makes for very cool character fluff, in my opinion.

Also, as @GMJoe kindly pointed out, there is a core enchantment in the 3.5 Dungeon Master's Guide (pg. 225) called [*Merciful*](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Merciful) for only a +1 bonus.  You'll certainly want this (assuming you don't use one of the weapons which already deals nonlethal damage):

> The weapon deals an extra 1d6 points of damage, and all damage it deals is nonlethal damage. On command, the weapon suppresses this ability until commanded to resume it. Bows, crossbows, and slings so crafted bestow the merciful effect upon their ammunition.

### Other Source Books

The best sources for nonlethal damage in books *outside* of core come from the [*Book of Exalted Deeds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Exalted_Deeds):

- pg. 34, Nonlethal Weapons: Contains, as you might expect, a broader range of weapons which only inflict nonlethal damage.  Can be upgraded per the normal magic item rules and you don't need to take the -4 attack bonus associated with the above rule.  Includes...

  - *Truncheon*: 1d8 nonlethal, bludgeoning, martial, one-handed melee weapon
  - *Entangling Pole*: 1d4 nonlethal, piercing, exotic, two-handed melee weapon
  - *Grasping Pole*: 1d4 nonlethal, bludgeoning, exotic, two-handed melee weapon
  - *Lasso* (yee-haw!): special, --, ranged weapon (10 ft.)
- pg. 40, Feats: There are a couple of feats which will allow you to deal nonlethal damage more effectively.  Again, all of these come at the cost of the feat, so they will still essentially make you *less effective* than someone doing lethal damage (who at least has one feat up on you).

  - [*Subduing Strike*](http://dndtools.eu/feats/book-of-exalted-deeds--52/subduing-strike--2808/): No penalty when dealing nonlethal damage;
    rogue’s sneak attack deals nonlethal damage
  - [*Holy Subdual*](http://dndtools.eu/feats/book-of-exalted-deeds--52/holy-subdual--1404/): Transform bonus and smite damage to nonlethal
  - [*Nonlethal Substitution*](http://dndtools.eu/feats/book-of-exalted-deeds--52/nonlethal-substitution--2071/): Transform spell’s energy damage to nonlethal
  - [*Vow of Nonviolence*](http://dndtools.eu/feats/book-of-exalted-deeds--52/vow-of-nonviolence--3078/): +4 to spell DC if it does not deal real damage
  - [*Vow of Peace*](http://dndtools.eu/feats/book-of-exalted-deeds--52/vow-of-peace--3080/): *calm emotions* aura, +2 natural AC, +2 deflection AC, +2 exalted AC, some normal weapons shatter when they contact you, +4 Diplomacy

### Optimal Build (?)

So, really, it looks like your best bet would be to become a traditional, overpowered spellcaster, take the *Nonlethal Substitution* feat (which will allow you to use your spells to deal nonlethal damage), then use the various *Vow* feats to increase your other statistics.  That looks like maximum leverage to me.  I don't know of any other source books that would really contribute much to this effort.

## Addendum

As far as dealing *more* damage than a normal damage dealer, that is likely next to impossible without being very, very creative.  For starters, there just aren't that many sources of nonlethal damage in the core rules.  If you look in the [Environment section](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/environment.htm), it might be possible for you to make some homebrew rules with your DM based on these (i.e., cold effects which numb instead of kill).  If you want to stay strictly within the RAW, though, I think your best bet for having a highly functioning nonlethal character would be to have a spellcaster of some kind who only utilizes *sleep* spells, *hold person* spells, and the like.  I didn't include this in the main answer because these effects don't technically deal *damage*, but it's an option which may appeal to you.

Comment: I am interested in builds that specifically leverage this mechanic usefully - simply taking the penalty with no additional benefits is not a build or likely viable at all.  What about feat or prestige-class options?

Comment: @SouthpawHare Your best bet then is looking through the *Book of Exalted Deeds*, some details of which I added to the post above.  Regardless, you will never be *more* effective than someone else doing nonlethal damage; you will at least have to either use inferior weapons or sacrifice some feats.  D&D 3.5 is pretty widely known for not being an "all builds are viable" kind of game.

Comment: Thank you.  You have provided exactly what I am looking for, although I wish to wait for other answers to see if there are in fact options that you are not aware of.

Comment: This answer doesn't mention the *merciful* weapon enchantment, which (from memory) is from the core, is equivalent in cost to a +1 bonus, and both increases the damage done by a weapon by 1d6 and makes all damage dealt by that weapon nonleathal. As options on how to do more damage than a leathal-damage dealing non-caster, it's one of the best.

Comment: @GMJoe Very true!  Can't believe that skipped my mind.  Do you mind if I add it to my answer?  Also, do you happen to know if that enchantment was available in the 3.0 DMG?  I actually played 3.0 much more than I played 3.5, so some of the 3.5 nuances are bit more "academic" and a bit less "internalized" for me, haha.

Comment: @GMJoe I'm going to sleep shortly, so I'm going to edit that into my answer.  If you'd like to add your own answer instead, just let me know and I'll remove it from my own. :)

Comment: @JeffGohlke I'm not great with RAW (I've a poor memory for details), so I prefer to suggest changes to existing RAW answers than to contribute my own. Also, I started roleplaying in 2004, just in time to miss the 3.0 boom; Later, I got interested in Pathfinder, 2e AD&D and retroclones in that order - and so 3.0 is somehow the edition I know the least about. It's funny how life can turn out.

Comment: A non-lethal light weapon in core (the blackjack) and a one-handed weapon which english name I don't know that's essentially a bigger version of it also exist in 3.5, without taking BoED into consideration. Natural weapons also don't get the -4 penalty to deal non-lethal damage, which is good for druids and transmuters. Feel free to add that to your answer.

Comment: @Zachiel Do you have a source for the natural weapons not taking a penalty?  Can't seem to find that rule anywhere.

Comment: @JeffGohlke Mmmmhhh, can't find it. Maybe it was some reminiscence from 3.0 or an houserule in my first D&D group.

Comment: Vow of Peace/Nonviolence are ***extremely*** game-warping feats that literally mean you are no longer playing *Dungeons & Dragons*. The overall system does not support the kinds of characters who would take those feats, and more importantly, even if you want to force a square peg through the round hole, ***those feats also change the game for your allies.*** If they ever should be taken, which is a big if, it is ***only*** after you receive the approval of every other player in the game. I would not allow someone who showed up with those feats without prior discussion to play in my game.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to build a non-lethal melee build to keep up in comparative damage to lethal combat, I recommend the Justiciar Prestige Class. Found on pages 47-48 of the Complete Warrior source-book, The Justiciar is a full base attack progression class with good will saves. Appears to be intended for rogue or ranger classes (Entry reqs include the Track feat/class ability and 5 ranks of Gather Information, as well as Skill Focus- Gather Info) who want to play the period-appropriate "cop" (must be lawful alignment) or the "Worth more alive than dead" bounty hunter type. This class, for a 1-level dip, offers "Bring them Back Alive" and 1d6 "Nonlethal Strikes" which functions as (and stacks with) Sneak Attack, but only applies when using "Bring em back alive".

> Bring ’em Back Alive (Ex): Whenever a justiciar attacks
>   with a melee weapon, he can deal nonlethal damage with
>   the weapon instead of lethal damage with no penalty on the
>   attack roll. Normally, attempting to deal nonlethal damage
>   with a weapon in this way incurs a –4 penalty on the attack
>   roll.

Pair this class with a class like rogue, ranger, or scout, the "Merciful" ability applied to any 2-handed weapon, a mid-range Intelligence score, and other standard melee build styles, and you should at *least* be able to keep pace damage-wise with a melee ranger.

---

As an added potential use, I used this PrC with a Razorclaw Shifter Rokugan Ninja/Scout build and the Vow of Poverty feat with the Vow of Nonviolence and Vow of Peace from BoED. The party Arcane Hierophant cast Greater Magic Weapon on my unarmed strike/claws and used permanency to make them stick. I followed up this class with levels of Kensai to improve my natural weapons. I ended up working as the "Royal Bounty Hunter", bringing Criminals back to the Capital for trial through 3 kingdoms...